# node js async function won't stop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to break from the loop in an async function in node js, but it seems not to work. Once the script it's done, it starts executing again from the beginning. I can't use process.exit(), because then it won't save my logs.
Any idea how can I terminate this function?

Here is the code:

```
async function program() {
 const xlsxFile = require('read-excel-file/node');
 let rows = await xlsxFile('./file.xlsx', { sheet: 'sheet' });

 const userRolesArray = [rows[0][1], rows[0][2]];

 let roles = await getAllRoles();
 let users = await getAllUsers();

 let count = 0;

 roleId = null;
 for (userRole in userRolesArray) {
   for (i in rows){
   
      let someObject = {
          test1: rows[i][0],
          test1: rows[i][2],
           
      };

       if (someObject.test1 =='undefined') {
            fs = require('fs')
            await fs.appendFile('log_file.txt', i+")"+JSON.stringify(someObject)+"\n", function (err) {
              if (err) throw err;
              // console.log('Saved!');
            });
          } else {
            //do something else;
          }
      }
}  
  count++;
  if (userRole === '1') {
    // loop has reached the end...Now exit
    break;
  }
};
program().then(() => {
 return "Finished....!"
});
```

Comment: _"Once the script it's done, it starts executing again from the beginning"_ Would you happen to use `nodemon`?

Comment: @blex, I've tried hours to solve this. 
Yes I was using nodemon. 
I am new to node js. It seems that to be the case.
Thank you very much...

Comment: It's restarting your script because it sees a file change when you write your log file. You can ignore it by creating a `nodemon.json` file at the root of your project with this content: `{"ignore": ["*/**.txt"] }`

Comment: @blex thanks again!!